# scala spark - matching dataframes based on variable dates

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to match two dataframes based on a variable date window. I am not simply trying to get an exact match, which my code achieves but to get all likely candidates within a variable day window.

I was able to get exact matches on dates with my code.

But I want to find out if the records are still viable to match since they could be a few days off either side but would still be reasonable enough to join on.

I've tried looking for something similar to python's `pd.to_timedelta('1 day')` in spark  to add to the filter but alas have struck no luck.

Here is my current code which matches the dataframe on the **ID** column and then runs a filter to ensure that the **from_date** in the second dataframe is between the **start_date** and the **end_date** of the first dataframe.

What I need is not the exact date match but be able to match records if they fall between a day or two (either side) of the actual dates.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

val df1 = spark.read.option("header","true")
               .option("inferSchema","true").csv("../data/df1.csv")

val df2 = spark.read.option("header","true")
               .option("inferSchema","true")
               .csv("../data/df2.csv")

val df = df2.join(df1,
                      (df1("ID") === df2("ID")) &&
                      (df2("from_date") >= df1("start_date")) &&
                      (df2("from_date") <= df1("end_date")),"left")
            .select(df1("ID"), df1("start_date"), df1("end_date"), 
                                                  $"from_date", $"to_date")

df.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true").save("../mydata.csv")
```

---

Essentially I want to be able to edit this date window to increase or decrease the data actually matching.

Would really appreciate your input. I'm new to spark/scala but gotta say I'm loving it so far ... soo much faster (and cleaner) than python!

**cheers**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply [date_add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@date_add(start:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,days:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and [date_sub](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@date_sub(start:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,days:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to `start_date/end_date` in your `join` condition, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.sql.Date

val df1 = Seq(
  (1, Date.valueOf("2018-12-01"), Date.valueOf("2018-12-05")),
  (2, Date.valueOf("2018-12-01"), Date.valueOf("2018-12-06")),
  (3, Date.valueOf("2018-12-01"), Date.valueOf("2018-12-07"))
).toDF("ID", "start_date", "end_date")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, Date.valueOf("2018-11-30")),
  (2, Date.valueOf("2018-12-08")),
  (3, Date.valueOf("2018-12-08"))
).toDF("ID", "from_date")

val deltaDays = 1

df2.join( df1,
  df1("ID") === df2("ID") &&
  df2("from_date") >= date_sub(df1("start_date"), deltaDays) &&
  df2("from_date") <= date_add(df1("end_date"), deltaDays),
  "left_outer"
).show
// +---+----------+----+----------+----------+
// | ID| from_date|  ID|start_date|  end_date|
// +---+----------+----+----------+----------+
// |  1|2018-11-30|   1|2018-12-01|2018-12-05|
// |  2|2018-12-08|null|      null|      null|
// |  3|2018-12-08|   3|2018-12-01|2018-12-07|
// +---+----------+----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results using datediff() function also. Check this out:

```
scala> val df1 = Seq((1,  "2018-12-01", "2018-12-05"),(2,  "2018-12-01", "2018-12-06"),(3,  "2018-12-01", "2018-12-07")).toDF("ID", "start_date", "end_date").withColumn("start_date",'start_date.cast("date")).withColumn("end_date",'end_date.cast("date"))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, start_date: date ... 1 more field]

scala> val df2 = Seq((1,  "2018-11-30"), (2,  "2018-12-08"),(3,  "2018-12-08")).toDF("ID", "from_date").withColumn("from_date",'from_date.cast("date"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, from_date: date]

scala> val delta = 1;
delta: Int = 1

scala> df2.join(df1,df1("ID") === df2("ID") && datediff('from_date,'start_date) >= -delta && datediff('from_date,'end_date)<=delta, "leftOuter").show(false)
+---+----------+----+----------+----------+
|ID |from_date |ID  |start_date|end_date  |
+---+----------+----+----------+----------+
|1  |2018-11-30|1   |2018-12-01|2018-12-05|
|2  |2018-12-08|null|null      |null      |
|3  |2018-12-08|3   |2018-12-01|2018-12-07|
+---+----------+----+----------+----------+


scala>
```